# F# desktop-support

Tags: .net, templates, f#, visual-studio-project

I need to add a F# .Net Framework project to an existing solution (with older .Net Framework projects, mostly C#).

I have all the install options for F# (optional items) selected:

[image]

If I previously selected the F# .Net Framework

[image]

All worked fine (in earlier versions of Visual Studio 2019).

In the meantime I installed serveral updates and I am now running on Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 v16.7.2.

Now, if I create a new F# .Net Framework project (to add to the solution) I always get a project with a Dependencies folder instead of a References folder.

[image]

Also can't run it, it gives error:
[image]

What need I to do to get a F# project with the References folder again?

[image]

Comment: This is correct. I see the same structure in VS 2019 (16.8 Preview 2). I assume it tries to get FSharp.Core from nuget while restoring dependencies. You could getting it manually or try a different version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct, it has to do with the .Net Framework versions. Defaults to .Net Standard as of .Net 4.6 or so ...